# jScrollPane bind to arrow buttons

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I'm using the jScrollPane plugin and I need to bind the actions to a couple of arrow buttons I have instead of using the scrollbar/arrows that are generated by the plugin. I found the following code which gets me half way there:

```
var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
$('#scroll-up').bind('click', function () {
    api.scrollByY(-10);
    return false;
});
$('#scroll-down').bind('click', function () {
    api.scrollByY(10);
    return false;
});
```

Which works fine for what it is, but what I actually need is for it to scroll as it would if you enabled arrowScrollOnHover. JS/jQuery is not my strong suit so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hover` function of `jQuery` as follows,

http://jsfiddle.net/RZecw/

**js**

```
var stopScrollingDown = true,stopScrollingUp = true;
var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
$('#scroll-up').hover(

function () {
    stopScrollingUp = false;
    scrollUp();
}, function () {
    stopScrollingUp = true;
});
$('#scroll-down').hover(function () {
    stopScrollingDown = false;
    scrollDown();
}, function () {
    stopScrollingDown = true;
});

function scrollUp() {
    if (!stopScrollingUp) {
        api.scrollByY(-10);
        setTimeout(scrollUp, 80);/*the smaller this value (80) is the faster it will move*/
    }
}

function scrollDown() {
    if (!stopScrollingDown) {
        api.scrollByY(10);
        setTimeout(scrollDown, 80);
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="scroll-pane"> <b>An Iframe at the bottom</b>

    <p>This demonstration shows basic use of the jScrollPane plugin to add scrollbars to a HTML which can be styled at will.This demonstration shows basic use of the jScrollPane 
....
</div>
<div id="scroll-up" class="btn">[up]</div>
<br/>
<div id="scroll-down" class="btn">[down]</div>
```

**css**

```
.scroll-pane {
    height:100px;
}
.btn{
    display:inline;
}
```

**EDIT - related to comments**

To hide/disable the buttons if there is no need for the content to scroll you can check if a drag handle exists. For example you can add at the end of the code the following snippet,

http://jsfiddle.net/RZecw/2/

```
if(!$('.jspDrag').length){
  /*hide controls or disable them*/
  /*$('.btn').css({visibility:"hidden"});*/
  $('.btn').css({color:"lightgray"});
  $('.btn').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
}
```

Comment: You're awesome, worked perfectly. Thank you! Sorry, is there a way to use this method to hide the buttons if there isn't an overflow of content, or should I just do it a different way?

Comment: @Nick thanks i'm glad it worked out for you. You can check if a drag handle is shown and act accordignly e.g. `if(!$('.jspDrag').length){/*hide controls or disable them*/}`